# Selenium innerHTML list, print specific value

Tags: python, selenium, innerhtml

First of all, I'm new to working with Python, especially Selenium. So I connected to a page with the webdriver and also already grabbed the InnerHTML I need. Here's my problem, InnerHTML is a "list" and I only want to output one value. It looks something like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <pre style="example" xpath="1">
   "amount": 12{
   "value" : 3
    },
  </pre>
 </body>
</html>
```

^It's just for illustration, because the actual thing is much longer. InnerHTML looks like this:

```
"amount": 12{
   "value" : 3
    },
```

^This is where I am now. I can't specify a line because the page is not static. How do I make python find "value" from a variable in InnerHTML ? Please note that there is a colon after "value"!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using regular expression to find the value. I assume that you only need the *number* part, so here's the code:

```py
innerHTML = '''
"amount": 12{
   "value" : 3
    },"value":4
    'value': 5
'''

import re
regex = re.compile(r'''("|')value("|')\s*:\s*(?P<number>\d+)''')
startpos = 0
m = None

while 1:
    m = regex.search(innerHTML, startpos)
    if m is None: break
    print(m.group("number"))
    startpos = m.start() + 1

# output:
# 3
# 4
# 5
```

This will print out all the value numbers found, as strings. You can convert them to integers afterwards, for example.
**NOTE**: My code also accounts for the case `value` is surrounded by single quotes `'` rather than double quotes `"`. This is for your convenience; if not, you can change the appropriate line above to:

```py
regex = re.compile(r'''"value"\s*:\s*(?P<number>\d+)''')
```

In that case, the output would not include the value `5`.